# Python Script Not Running Through Command Line

Tags: python, user-interface, python-2.7, random, command-line

I'm baffled as to why the command line isn't able to run a certain script when the Python GUI can. What i'm trying to run is:

```
import random
print random.random()
```

Which runs fine in the Python GUI but when saved as a file (random.py) and ran through the command line

```
C:\Users\Name>python c:\Python\random.py
```

it produces this error:

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Has anyone had this problem or know why it occurs?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you have overridden the actual module `random` by creating your own `random.py`. Now, you're importing your own file which you're trying to call, and not actually importing the module which has the `random` function.

To fix this you need to do two things:

1. Rename your file to something other than `random.py`
2. Get rid of the `.pyc` created as a result of importing.

Comment: All fixed. Thanks for your help!